# Center a Logo via CSS in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes, margin

I'm trying to center the logo of a site ([here](http://rainleader.com)) in Canvas on Wordpress. I'm using this CSS:

```
#logo img {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I can manually move the logo like this, though:

```
#logo img {
display: block;
margin-left: 330px;
}
```

But, by forcing it with left-margin, it breaks the mobile site (moves the logo 3" over requiring scrolling).

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Why a canvas? And give the img a set width.

Comment: I checked the site, the logo not centered because it is floated left. Remove the float property from #logo and it should be centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your site an element with id = 'logo', has been floated to left by css.

Remove `float:left` declaration for this element.